# How to pass video between Xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have tow views in two different Xib, View1 and View2. In View2 I edit the video. What I need is to pass the video in View2 to View1 after I do some edit.

I have no idea how to make it. I know to pass (string or Image) but I do not know how to do it with video.

This is the code after I select Or record video in View2:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) // Media is a video
    {
        videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
        [self loadMoviePlayer:videoUrl];

    }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: are u talking about viewcontroller or view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSData to fetch content from video file or url of video and then pass this data object to view you want to pass.
example:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videofilePath];
```

or

```
  NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```